# Name in string c++

Tags: c++, string

My task this time is to write  program that  will create string where you input last and first name and then  program prints it in form :
Persons last name is **_** and first name is .
Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

void imeosobe(char *s,char *prezime,char *ime)
{
    int i,a=0,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        if(a==0) *(prezime+i)=*(s+i);
      else
      {
          *(ime+k)=*(s+i);
          k++;
      }
    if(s[i]=="" ) a=i;
}
    *(prezime+i-k)='\0';
    *(ime+k)='\0';


}



main()  
{

    char s1[50],prezime[50],ime[50];
    printf("Unesi prezime i ime:");
    gets(s1);
    imeosobe(s1,prezime,ime);
    printf("\nPrezime je %s,a ime %s ",prezime,ime);
    return 0;

}
```

I think that main problem is in **if(s[i]==" " ) a=i;** since last and first name must be separated with empty space (1 block=enough for 1  letter (one click of space)) but I'm not sure how to correct it

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
if(s[i]=="")
```

to

```
if(s[i] == ' ') // s[i] is a char, not a string
```

Comment: assuming only one space is entered!!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan only one space can be entered between single quotes

Comment: only 1 space is used...thx dude  l really had no idea about writing empty space like that...l did try '\0' but that didnt work :D  thx again :D

Comment: @PaulEvans My comment was message to OP that last-name and first-name should be separated by only one space.

Comment: @PaulEvans Actually it will also be OK if you use `'     '` (multiple spaces in single quote).

Comment: @user3127589 There is `ispace()` Also understand you   were comparing a string with a char! Note `"5"` is a string, `'5'` is a char and `5` is a number, three different kinds of constants.

Comment: `0x20` will translate to a `' '` as-well